# Cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect when using redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I found many similar questions but most of solution are without redux solution. I would like to call subscriptions after delete item from redux store.

Below is the codes that I cancel all subscriptions but I am not sure that I am doing right way!

```
const useFetchProperty = (propertyId, refresh = false) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const property = useSelector(state => selectPropertyById(state, propertyId));
  const isConnected = useIsConnected();

  useEffect(() => {
    let isSubscribed = true;
    if (
      isSubscribed &&
      isConnected &&
      (property === undefined || refresh === true)
    ) {
      dispatch(fetchProperty({propertyId: propertyId}));
    }
    return () => (isSubscribed = false);
  }, [dispatch, refresh, isConnected, property, propertyId]);

  return property;
};

export default useFetchProperty;
```

CarDesign.js

```
const CardDesign = ({postId}) => {
  const {t} = useContext(LocalizationContext);
  const post = useFetchProperty(postId);
  const currentLanguage = useSelector(currentAppLanguage);
  const navigation = useNavigation();

//the rest show data would be here
}
```

You would see I am using these two
`let isSubscribed = true;` and `return () => (isSubscribed = false);`. Is it correct way to cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks with dispatch ???

Here is screenshot for that error I got.
[image: subscription error]

Answer (score 0):

Your `isSubscribe` variables scope is inside the `useEffect` so there is no need to do the following

```
return () => (isSubscribed = false);
```

The reason is - When your useEffect will take a new effect the isSubscribe will always have `true` because of the variable declaration. As the scope is inside the `useEffect` so removing the return will solve that

But if you really need to use it then declare the `isSubscribe` variable globally

Comment: Hi @moshfiqrony, sorry I am not clear that How it could can all subscription If I define globally or locally defining ```isSubscribe``` variable. I think defining variable only can't make to cancel all subscriptions.

Comment: The problem here is. You are defining the ```isSubscribed``` variable inside the useEffect and when the return is called the ```isSubscribed``` lose the context or memory. So what happen is it cannot execute the ```isSubscribed = false``` line. Because it is already unmounted.